# SSRS report with SharePoint site as a parameter

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

Easy question. Is it possible to have an SSRS report include a parameter so that the user can select a site (SPWeb) and to then run the report against a list within the selected site. I.e. We might have sites for project one, two and three, within each is a list "materials" depending on the project we select the report will show the materials.

Possible? Hints thankfully received!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you could do that is by having  SSRS call a webservice and have the .NET code call the Sharepoint API and do all the possible manipulations you need